# Importing chunks into the same table using sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I'm very new to hive and `sqoop`, as my company has just adopted them. As such, I am trying to import data from a `sql` database into `hdfs/hive`. However, we still only have a few clusters so I am worried about importing all the data at once (19 million records in total). I have searched furiously for a solution but the only thing close to what I am looking for that I have found is using incremental import. However, this is not a solution as it imports everything newer than the first import, and I have historical data for 2 years.

Therefore, is there a way to append to a table that I am missing (so I can import a month at a time into the same table for example?

Here is the initial command I am using to insert the first chunk of data into the table.

```
sqoop  import --driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver \
--connect jdbc:sqlserver://******omitted******* \
--username **** \
--password *******  \
--hive-table <tablename> \
--m 1 \
--delete-target-dir \
--target-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/<dir to table> \
--hive-drop-import-delims \
--hive-import --query "select * from  <old sql table> where record_id   
<='000000001433106' and \$CONDITIONS"
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there any sys_creation_date or related column on <old sql table > , that can be specified in `where` clause in query?

Comment: the record_id is a field which is automatically incremented/added to an insertion in the old table and as such is a good way to look at the table sequentially. There is a creation_date field which works in a similar way.